# Another prime formed by concatenating squares?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $n_k$ be the number emerging by concatenating the squares from $1$ to $k^2$, for example we have $$n_{10}=149162536496481100$$

$n_3=149$ is prime, but I did not find further primes of this form.

> Is there another prime $n_k$ ?

Comment: [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A019521) 149 is the only prime up to $k=4000$.

Comment: $$2|n_{2k}$$ and $$5|n_{5k}$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2408585/a-prime-formed-by-concanatting-fibonacci-numbers

Comment: with cubes I arrived at $500$ digits $n_{97}$ with no primes

Comment: $3|n_{9k},n_{9k+4},n_{9k+8}$.