# A prime formed by concatenating Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Denote $n_k$ for $k\le 2$ to be the number emerging by concatenating the Fibonacci numbers $F_2$ to $F_k$, so for example we have $$n_{10}=1235813213455$$

I begin with $F_2$ because in this variant I did not find a prime of this form yet, whereas beginning with $F_1$ gives the two primes $11$ and $1123$, but I did not find another prime.

> Is there a prime $n_k>1123$ in either variant ?

If there is such a prime, the index $k$ must satisfy $k>320$, and $n_k$ must have more than $10\ 000$ digits.

Comment: [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A019523) says it's unknown, although $k\geq 800$.

Comment: @Arthur which variant is used in OEIS ?

Comment: If you click where my comment says "OEIS", it's a link that takes you to the page. It's the one that begins with 11. The one that starts with 12 is not there.

Comment: Why don't you click at the link Arthur provided to find out? BTW, I have a few more ideas for new questions: a prime from concatenating consecutive cubes, a Fibonacci number from concatenating consecutive primes, etc.